# Search Field as formatted is slow

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I moved my MS Access split database to SQL Server. The find option used to be pretty fast before I moved my tables to SQL Server.

Now the find option takes 20 seconds what used to take less than 1 sec to find. However, if I uncheck the **Search Field as Formatted** option it only takes about 1 sec to find a record. The **Search Field as Formatted** option is selected by default and I think there is no way to keep it not selected.

[image]

Did anyone else face similar issues? How did you solve the speed issue?

Comment: Reading [MSDN about find and Replace](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-find-and-replace-dialog-box-to-change-data-2eee8d02-5a40-4328-ba56-ec0406865680?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) looks like there is no way to deactivate it by default, only manually. But maybe [Understanding the Search Fields as Formatted check box](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-find-and-replace-dialog-box-to-change-data-2eee8d02-5a40-4328-ba56-ec0406865680?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bmasformatted) can throw some light.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation in the past.  I built my own version of the "Find and Replace" form, where I could be in control of the defaults.  Also I believe I had to tweak some of the Client ODBC settings.